# HTML Canvas: Should my app x, y values be global?

Tags: javascript, architecture, html5, canvas

I have a large file of functions. Each of these functions is responsible for drawing a particular part of the application. My app has x and y parameters that I use in the setup function to move the whole app around in order to try different placements. So, naturally, I need to use these x and y values to anchor each function's component rendering so that everything moves in unison if the global x,y values ever change.

My question is, is it bad practice/architecture to have these x,y values in the global namespace and having the each function directly access them like so?

```
function renderFace() {
   var x = App.x;
   var y = App.y;

   // drawing here
}
```

is there a better way i'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

> ...is it bad practice/architecture to have these x,y values in the global namespace... like so?

In your code, your `x` and `y` *aren't* in the global namespace; they're properties of `App`. That's a good start: you're using `App.x` instead of `window.x`.

That said, `App` and `renderFace` are coupled: you can't apply the functional behavior of `renderFace` to anything but the values of `App.x`/`y`. If you want to reduce coupling to make `renderFace` more general, it might be better to have `renderFace` accept `x` and `y` as arguments:

```
function renderFace(x, y) {
   // drawing here
}
```

and have some invoking code call `renderFace(App.x, App.y)` instead of just `renderFace()`.

Alternatively, make your render functions actual methods of `App` and refer to the properties using `this`.

```
var App = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,

    renderFace: function() {
        var x = this.x;
        var y = this.y;

        // drawing here
    }
}
```

By having `App` "own" `renderFace` as a method, it indicates logically that `renderFace` is a behavior of `App`.

When someone reading your code sees `renderFace()`, they might not know it depends on the state of `App`. When they see `App.renderFace()` or `renderFace(App.x, App.y)` the relationship is explicitly clear. Furthermore, by moving the identifer `App` out of your function, it's easy to re-use `renderFace` in other non-`App` contexts later.